# Can't access new environment variables through Python os

Tags: python, operating-system, environment-variables

So I added some credentials to my env variables through Windows System options to access it in a more secure way, however whenver I try to get their values in Python (using os.environ) the keys aren't found. I've tried to reboot my computer, but this didn't help.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: @martineau 64-bit

Comment: @PaulP it's just a os.environ["the_name_I_gave"], however the key isn't found. I've created the environment variable through system advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

I could access them . Could you please check if environ variables are created successfully . Restart python console. I dont think we need to restart computer.

Comment: Hello there, I've created the variables through the system advanced options on windows. I've tried to restart the console, but it didn't work out. I even tried to create a new venv, but without success as well.

Comment: It's a KeyError, i.e. the os.environ dict wasn't updated from my environment variable addition.

Comment: Print any other variables from the environment.You might also check user variable and system variables